# react js bundle files rending in header tag instead of body tag

Tags: reactjs, salesforce, visualforce, salesforce-lightning

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false"
       showHeader="false" applyBodyTag="true" applyHtmlTag="false"
       docType="html-5.0" >
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <title>React in VF</title>
        <apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.style}"/>   
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.reactchunckbundle1}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.reactchunckbundle2}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.reactchunckbundle3}"/>  
    </body>
    
</html> </apex:page>
```

[source image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqtBb.png)

because it's rending on header tag my script is not able to find `document.getElementById('root')`

Comment: Could you post a your index.html file? That might have something to do with it.

Comment: I am using Visualfoce page (similar to html )  instead of index.html to trigger my reactjs

Answer (score 0):

Fix `loadOnReady`  attribute

- loadOnReady attribute have two value i.e false and true. Default
  value of this attribute is false. If value of this attribute is false
  then script load immediately. If value of this attribute is true then
  script will load when page is ready.

Example:

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.reactchunckbundle1}" loadOnReady="true"/>
```